# wso2 - http PDF response - save file on WSO2 server instead of download

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I want to save PDF file from response directly on WSO2 server. When I open API URL in browser, Chrome automatically download file on my local computer. How can I save this file directly on WSO2 server?

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" context="/test">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/test*">
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <root>
                  <mtfId>150</mtfId>
                  <orderSno>50339375</orderSno>
               </root>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="POST" uri-template="https://www.proceedo.net/suppliercenter/common/orderexport.do"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the file connector to create a file in the ESB server. Please refer to [1] on how to set up the file connector and you can use the file connector create operation [2] to achieve your requirement.

```
<fileconnector.create>
    <filePath>{$ctx:filePath}</filePath>
    <inputContent>{$ctx:inputContent}</inputContent>
    <encoding>{$ctx:encoding}</encoding>
    <setTimeout>{$ctx:setTimeout}</setTimeout>
    <setPassiveMode>{$ctx:setPassiveMode}</setPassiveMode>
    <setSoTimeout>{$ctx:setSoTimeout}</setSoTimeout>
    <setUserDirIsRoot>{$ctx:setUserDirIsRoot}</setUserDirIsRoot>
    <setStrictHostKeyChecking>{$ctx:setStrictHostKeyChecking}</setStrictHostKeyChecking>
</fileconnector.create>
```

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/File+Connector
[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector#WorkingwiththeFileConnector-create